# Networking restart not working?

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian-jessie

In My raspberry Pi wifi is connected to my home wifi and eth0 is assigned with a static ip address. It act as a router between wlan0 and eth0. Raspberry pi get internet through the wifi.

After modifying the wpa_supplicant.conf, i restarted the service networking using `sudo service networking restart`. This restart the network but raspberry pi is not connected to the home wifi.

But it connects when we reboot the system.

Answer (score 3):

After modifying wpa_supplicant.conf you need to make wpa_supplicant re-read the  configuration file.

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure
```

(assuming wlan0 is your wifi to reconfigure)

reference - [wpa_cli man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_cli)

Comment: Yeah. But this command disconnect the Raspberry Pi from the internet even if the Rpi is connected to Home wifi. So i need to reboot the system for internet connection.

Comment: If you want to modify the wifi connection using wpa_supplicant then it's going to disconnect the WiFi while it reconfigures,   If the WiFi provides Internet connection then that connection will return when the Wifi comes back up. You'll have to make sure that routing is also set correctly after reconfiguring the wifi.  The wpa_cli command will work to reconfigure the wifi connection, but you may need addtitional commands to re-establish the network routing.  When you reboot the routing is set up after the wifi is reconfigured.

Comment: on rebooting its work correctly. after running reconfiguration, wifi is connected and ip address is assigned to wlan0 but no internet is getting.  So to re-establish the internet connection i restarted the networking service but it disconnected from wifi.

Comment: wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure produce `Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: wlan0  error: No such file or directory` error

Comment: What i have to do after giving `wpa_cli reconfigure` to get the internet? How the internet is getting while rebooting?